# XSLT combine multiple function

Tags: xml, xslt

It is a good idea to combine multiple XSLT functions into one single line?

```
<xsl:template match="title" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(replace(replace(.,'OK',''),'^.\d+Something',''),'((Special10)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)','$1$3'))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a more readable solution than this?

Comment: See the answer from @MartinHonnen. If you don't have XPath 3.1 support, you can bind intermediate results to variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 you can use the arrow operator `=>` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrow-operator) to write e.g.

```
normalize-space(replace(replace(replace(.,'OK',''),'^.\d+Something',''),'((Special10)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)','$1$3'))
```

as

```
. => replace('OK', '') => replace('^.\d+Something','') => replace('((Special10)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)','$1$3') => normalize-space()
```

You can compare both versions at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoq,

which does

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="title" >
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(replace(replace(.,'OK',''),'^.\d+Something',''),'((Special10)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)','$1$3'))"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title2" expand-text="yes">
        <xsl:copy>{. => replace('OK', '') => replace('^.\d+Something','') => replace('((Special10)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)','$1$3') => normalize-space()}</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Very nice solution. From what Saxon version it is supported? With standard version of Xsltransform (Saxon 9.5.x) I get error 500: http://xsltransform.net/3MEbY6p

Comment: XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 is supported in all editions only with Saxon 9.8. I would think that earlier versions of Saxon EE and PE support it as well as they usually implemented working drafts of  XSLT respectively XPath 3. http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/expressions/xpath31new.html suggests the arrow operator is supported in 9.7 EE/PE. Based on http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/expressions/xpath30new.html it doesn't look to be a feature implemented in 9.6.

Comment: In the meantime I found this information. And now I will be OFF topic. :/ Currently, I am trying to add Saxon 9.8 to my local Xsltransform copy. I found your fork @Github, but there is only a revert "updating to 9.8" commit, but on the site that you are linking is a 9.8 version. Do you have any information how it is possible to update Xsltransform to 9.8 version? https://github.com/joepjoosten/XSL-tester/issues/14

Comment: As for http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/, it is an ASP.NET MVC 5 "clone" I did of the Java/Scala play framework app that xsltransform.net is based on, so it has a completely different backend, using the .NET version of Saxon 9.8 HE as its XSLT 3 processor, and using the Microsoft Entity Framework for data base access. So that is not an update you can do to your local copy of xsltransform I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you, I hope the original author of the Xsltransform is continue on development in the future. Until then I am going to use your version when I need to.